# How can change the font for the title of the main frame in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, jupyter

```
# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("550x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title("Split files by bookmark")
```

The heading "Split files by bookmark" is small and faint and I want to make it display large, bold and colored.   Prefixing and suffixing the string with double asterisks or special codes does not work for me.   I do not know how to include markdown text.

Comment: I forgot to include the need for    import tkinter as tk    in my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Tkinter doesn't give you the ability to change the font that is used by the OS for the window, or to change the colors. You'll have to find some sort of platform-specific tool to do that.